# How do I handle an intent URI like this in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

This is the URI:

> intent://maps.google.com/maps?client=javelin&um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=Conrad+Centennial+Singapore+Hotel&fb=1&hq=Conrad+Centennial+Singapore+Hotel&hnear=Conrad+Centennial+Singapore+Hotel&entry=s&ll=1.293491,103.858673&z=15&cid=16931588425096815987&sa=X&ei=jvRbU-z8J83xiAeEhYCABA&ved=0CDwQ_BI#Intent;scheme=http;package=com.google.android.apps.maps;end

This is the URL I get when I click on it on a mobile browser.

I'd like to know not specifically how to open google maps via an intent. rather, how can i handle URIs with the format starting with `intent://`

Comment: i'd like to know not specifically how to open google maps via an intent. rather, how can i handle URIs with the format starting with intent://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i handle URIs with the format starting with intent://

All Android apps automatically "handle URIs with the format starting with intent://".

This URL will be parsed by `Intent.parseUri()` and used with `startActivity()` by the system. In this case, it will bring up Google Maps (`package=com.google.android.maps`) with a `Uri` of `http://maps.google.com/maps?client=javelin&um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=Conrad+Centennial+Singapore+Hotel&fb=1&hq=Conrad+Centennial+Singapore+Hotel&hnear=Conrad+Centennial+Singapore+Hotel&entry=s&ll=1.293491,103.858673&z=15&cid=16931588425096815987&sa=X&ei=jvRbU-z8J83xiAeEhYCABA&ved=0CDwQ_BI` (everything after the original scheme up to the fragment marker, replacing the scheme with `http` based upon the `scheme=http` directive).

You can create such an `intent://` URL via the `toUri()` method on `Intent`. Create an `Intent` that does what you want, then call `toUri()` on it to generate the appropriate URL.

Unfortunately, most of the logic for how to construct such URLs is undocumented.